# paypal button for buy 1 year, get 6 months free

Tags: paypal

I want to make a Paypal button for buy 1 year, get 6 months free

It's rather easy to setup a free trial period, but in that case the first billing doesn't hit until the trial period is finished.  That sucks.

We want to run a promotion where the free trial period comes at the END.  So they pay for a full year today, and aren't billed again for another 18 months, at which point they are billed for another year of service, and the yearly billing cycle continues from there.

Billing for the trial period of 18 months won't solve my problem because there are 3 different checkout options and the trial period applies to all of them as a whole (they are different prices).

We have 3 subscription types, and 3 promotions.  So it seems like I have to make 9 different buttons to solve my problem??  How can it be done a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this.  I just had to make a separate buttons for each.  For example:

I wanted the first subscription type to pay 1 year, get 6 months free....  In Paypal I selected yearly billing for X dollars, then chose an 18 months promotion (and the cost of the promotion was set to the same cost as the regular yearly billing).

This way, we get paid from the first second, the customer still gets their "free trial" which I guess isn't technically a free trial.  It's more like a 50% discount for the first 1.5 years.